# I want to use Task Scheduler to run a .jpg file. Under 'Action', I have to input the path of Windows Photo Viewer. What is the path?

Tags: windows-10, path, task-scheduler, windows-photo-viewer

I want to use Task Scheduler to run a .jpg file. Under the 'Action' tab, I have to input the path of Windows Photo Viewer. Can anyone tell me what the path is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> rundll32.exe "C:\Program Files\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll",
>   ImageView_Fullscreen

Example:

> rundll32.exe "C:\Program Files\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll",
>   ImageView_Fullscreen d:\test\somefile 007.jpg

No quotes to be added around the file name.

Comment: Thanks. It works, although I have to separately input `rundll32.exe` as the program and  input `"C:\Program Files\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen d:\test\somefile 007.jpg` as the arguments.